# missing externel ports when trying to configure constraints in vivado 2018.3

Tags: xilinx, vivado, zynq

i made this design in vivado 2018.3:

[image]

the synthesis runs ok , but after that when i open the synthesised design to do the port mapping i cant find find all the ports some are missing , and only 8 ports exist :

[image]